# Start Microsoft Teams minimised (but not hidden)

Tags: windows, microsoft-teams

We use Microsoft Teams. After booting the computer and seeing the Windows desktop, Teams pops up as a normal window after a few seconds delay. This is annoying because you might be typing something as Teams pops up.

The registry setting for launching Teams at startup is defined as follows:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
"com.squirrel.Teams.Teams"="C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Teams\\Update.exe --processStart \"Teams.exe\" --process-start-args \"--system-initiated\""
```

In Settings > General, I tried `Open application in background`. After rebooting, Teams now starts completely hidden (not visible on the Taskbar), which is not what I want.

Comment: Hmmm I also have the setting "open application in background" and I still see Teams in the Taskbar - not sure if you have a real issue here. Maybe it works now?

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate the default Setting "Auto-start application" in your Teams client Settings and [create your own shortcut with the Property set to minimize the application](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-automatically-start-a-program-minimized-in-windows/) that you then put into your Startup folder.

You could also easily do this with an AutoHotkey script. I like to use [Workspace.ahk](https://gist.github.com/tdalon/60da20e1e2203ded15ab2c4b8bde33fe) to start up my applications.